# There does not exist $c \ge 0$ such that $\|f\|_{\max} \le c\|f\|_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $f \in C[a,b]$ and let $\|f\|_1$ be the $\mathcal{L}^{1}$-norm and $\|f\|_{\max} = \max_{x \in [a,b]}|f|$. They are both norms on the given vector space. I want to prove that $\not \exists c \ge 0$ such that

$$\|f\|_{\max} \le c\|f\|_1$$

I tried to argue by contradiction but there was not luck for me. Is that the method or should I try something else?

Comment: you can take $f = Ax+B$, then let $A\rightarrow \infty$, then there is no constant $c$.

Comment: Well, it should work for any $f \in C[a,b]$. Unless you can prove that every such $f$ is of the form you propose (which I don't think is the case) then finding one such $f$ does not suffice.

Comment: @Stefan: In more detail: By logic, saying that $\not \exists c \geq 0$ such that for all $f \in C[a,b]$ we have $\Vert f \Vert_\text{max} \leq c \Vert f \Vert_1$ is equivalent to saying that: for all $n \geq 0$, there exists an $f_n \in C[a,b]$ such that $\Vert f_n \Vert_{\text{max}} > n \Vert f_n \Vert_1$.  Now use Yimin's comment with $f_n(x) = nx + b$.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the clarification! Many thanks to @Yimin as well and apologies for not understanding immediately!

Comment: @Stefan: Actually... Going through the calculation now, I don't think Yimin's example sequence works, so you'll need a different one... But you see what you have to do, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[a,b]$ be the interval $[-1,1]$. We will prove that the ratio $\frac{\|f\|_{max}}{\|f\|_1}$ is not bounded in $C[-1,1]$.
define a sequence of functions $f_n:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ by:

$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1-n|x| & |x| \le \frac{1}{n} \\
      0 & \textrm{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$

we have $\frac{\|f\|_{max}}{\|f\|_1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}=n$ which is greater than any constant $c$ for large enough $n$.

EDIT: for a general interval, a similar construction can be made.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f_n(x) = \left( \frac{x-a}{b-a} \right)^n $. Then $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$ for all $n$, and $\|f\|_1 = \frac{b-a}{n+1}$ for all $n$. So no such $c$ exists.